# Need browser with websocket and full screen mode support

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

I need a browser that supports **websocket and full screen mode** and where I can set a **default homepage**.

The device that I am using is Rikomagic **MK802 III**. I am using a startup program to open a browser in full screen mode with a default URL when the machine is booted.

The default stock Android browser works fine, but **does not support websocket**. It also does not have a very good support for JavaScript.

Next, I tried with Chrome, Firefox and Opera. All of them support websocket and works fine. **But none of them have a provision to set a default homepage and full screen also is not supported.**

However I found [an add-on in Firefox that supports full screen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/full-screen-252573/?src=hp-dl-featured), but don't know how to make this a default behavior when the browser is opened. Setting default homepage is still a problem.

Please suggest me what option I am left with. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: There is another addon, but somehow it is not supported for Firefox 18 and above. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-homepage/

Comment: Wow, I'm looking for the same solution and even using the same hardware. Are [SureFox](http://www.42gears.com/surefox/surefoxandroid.html) and [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html) the apps you're currently using to open the URL fullscreen on startup? If not, please share what you're using, and give them a shot - might be what you're looking for (though requires root, let me know if you need a hand with it since I documented the process last night.)

Comment: Hi Mark, that would be great. You can share the document. Yes, finally I got Dolphin Browser to do the trick and I used "start" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.niwota.start) to start the browser at boot time. Now to hide bottom bar or system bar, we can use "hidebar" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.hidebar). **except for hidebar, I tried everything and it works**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [Chrome For Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/overview) (not the Android stock Browser) does have Websocket support, and you can set a default homepage, not sure about Fullscreen mode though.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Dolphin](http://dolphin-browser.com/) was a web browser specifically designed for the Android Platform.

It was so successful it was then introduced for iOS devices.

I don't know if it will accomplish your needs, but if it can't then...

You can [get it from Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

Alternatively you may like to try Maxathon Cloud based Browser http://www.maxthon.com/

Comment: Does Dolphin support websocket ? I do not see this in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: @user644745: In my answer I stated "I don't know if it will accomplish your needs, but if it can't then..."

Comment: It supports websocket and I can set a default home page. trying to find out if i can make it full screen.

Comment: @user644745: I hope it works out, as it was specifically made for Android. I know it was highly rated amongst Android users and thats why iOS users wanted a version of their own (which they eventualy got). Hopefully it will :)